# How to set the width of a table cell including border, margin and padding?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I am trying to implement a table resizing feature for the user to drag the vertical bar of a cell to adjust the width. For doing that, I need to set the td width using something like below:

```
td.style.width = '20px'
```

but this css style width doesn't include the width of the border, margin and padding, which will cause some jumping effect while resizing multiple cell. So, I have to manually calculate the border, margin and padding for each cell and get an offset value, then do something like

```
td.style.width = `${20-offset}px`
```

but this approach is so bug prone. So basically, I want to set the width of the **WHOLE** cell including border, margin, and padding, to be 20px in this example. I am wondering if there is a simpler way to do that without calculating these values. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try using the css `td {box-sizing: border-box;}`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: Awesome! That is really helpful. Thank you so much !